# Posting data to node.js never returns anything

Tags: node.js

When posting data from jquery to a node.js process sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't. It depends on how I structure the code. This way it works:

```
http.createServer(router).listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/');

function router(req, res){
    var page = url.parse(req.url, true);

        switch(page.pathname){
            case '/new-task': tasks.postNewTask(req, res); break;
        }

}
```

"tasks" is a module I load. Inside there's postNewTask:

```
function postNewTask(req, res){
    core.postRequest(req, res, function () {
    // lots of stuff inside
    })
}
```

postRequest is a function I "borrowed" here from Stackoverflow. It's defined as:

```
function postRequest(request, response, callback) {
    var queryData = "";
    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return null;

if(request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log("it's post");
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("it's data");
        queryData += data;
        if(queryData.length > 1e6) {
            console("too much stuff");
            queryData = "";
            response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            request.connection.destroy();
        }
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        console.log("it's end");
        response.post = querystring.parse(queryData);
        callback();
    });

} else {
    console.log("no post");
    response.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end();
}
}
```

This works perfectly and and the code inside tasks.postNewTask runs. However when I change the router to this:

```
function router(req, res){
 var page = url.parse(req.url, true);

 var session = core.getCookies(req).s;    
if (page.pathname == '/login') {    

core.postLogin(req, res); return; }



 database.query('SELECT * from Members WHERE Session = ?;', [session], function(err, rows, fields) {

     if (err) throw err;
     if (rows.length>0) {

         switch(page.pathname){
             case '/new-task': tasks.postNewTask(req, res); break;
         }

     } else {
         res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
         res.end(JSON.stringify('login'));
     };
 });

 }
```

then postRequest no longer works. It will only print "it's post" and that's it. It never prints data or that it reaches end. It also seems to never return to the client as I get a timeout on the browser.

The problem here is that "data" and "end" events in postRequest are never called, when the only thing I changed was to wrap the database call around the switch statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 console outputs in postRequest

```
it's post
it's data
it's end
```

First is fired regardless because the if condition just checks for request type, rest two are done when request gets data and end signals, asynchronously. So if postNewTask returns or sends response to the request then it may not reach that part. Check what you are doing in `// lots of stuff inside`

Also on searching for your mysql documentation https://npmjs.org/package/mysql I found :

```
You MUST NOT provide a callback to the query() method when streaming rows.
```

So check on that too.